# Correct way to write a question

Tags: word-order, questions

What is the correct way:

> what will be our options after tomorrow?

or

> what will our options be after tomorrow?

Comment: is there a reason you think one is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

The normal order for non-subject questions in English is for the subject to follow the first word (only) of the verb phrase.

In most cases, that first word is an auxiliary, eg (auxiliary in *italics*; subject in **bold**):

> What *does* **that** mean?
>
> How *should* **I** do it?
>
> Who *have* **you** already talked to?

So you example should normally read

> What *will* **our options** be after tomorrow?

However, there is a reason why your second option might also be possible:

> What *will* be **our options** after tomorrow.

This pattern is available only if the main verb is *be*, and furthermore that it is identifying something, not saying where something is.

So you can say

> What *could* be **the real explanation for the phenomena**?

as well as

> What *could* **the real explanation for the phenomena** be?

and

> What *would* be **the point**?

as well as

> What *would* **the point** be?

and in those two cases, the form with "be" earlier sounds better to me. In your case, I find both options equally good.

You cannot do this with verbs other than "be":

> "What money *will* **they** have?" not * "What money *will* have **they**?
>
> "When *will* **the occupying forces** go?" not * "When *will* go **the occupying forces**?"

and you cannot do it when "be" means "be in a place"

> "Where *will* **your brother** be?" not * "Where *will* be **your brother**?"